# Agregar html a la fila de datables, utilizando ajax para los datos

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, datatables

Necesito agregar html de forma que cada fila sea un formulario para actualizar la base de datos, me encontraba imprimiendola mediante php pero con muchos datos se hace lento y requiero llamar los datos a traves de ajax, como podria ponerle las etiquetas de form a la fila como esta abajo?.

```
              <tr>
                <form method="post">
                  <td>Peperoni El Huerto Gr</td><input type="hidden" name="idProducto" value="158"><input type="hidden" name="idProducto" value="158">
                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Pasta" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Queso" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Tomate" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Queso_crema" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Salami" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Masa" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Jamon" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Queso_Final" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Peperoni" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Champiñon" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Bocadillo" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Maiz" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Tocineta" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Cebolla" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Pimenton" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Jalapeño" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Aceituna" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Chorizo" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Berenjena" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Atun" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Camaron" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Chocolate" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Brevas" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Azucar" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input style="width:80px;" type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="Sal" placeholder="0" value="0" required></div>
                      </td>

                  <td><input type="submit" name="productMod" value="Modificar"></td>
                </form>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm...No estoy muy seguro de entender lo que quieres. Pero de primeras decirte que hacer un formulario por cada linea no es muy recomendable.

Yo en su lugar añadiria una llamada a una función JavaScript en un evento onclick en el boton que creas al final. Algo así:

```
<input type="button" name="productMod" value="Modificar" onclick="funcionAjax()">
```

Dentro de la llamada a la función deberías de pasarle un id o algo único para poder obtener los diferentes datos de la fila.